# When I insert a new record is not displayed in the UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I created a Contact App populated with dummy data and when I try to insert a new contact is not appearing in my UITableView but if I printout my array is showing me that is there.
Also my delete is not working very well. Is deleting the whole section instead to delete my selected row.
Can you help me to fix my insert function and my delete function ?
Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
class Contact {
    var fullName: String
    var phoneNumber: String?

    init(fullName: String, phoneNumber: String) {
        self.fullName = fullName
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
    }
}


var contactsArray = [Contact]()

var sections = [[Contact]]()

// Logic functionality for my "Contact" application
class ContactViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var phoneTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var contactsTableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

 contactsTableView.delegate = self
        contactsTableView.dataSource = self
        phoneTextField.delegate = self

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        contactsTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ContactViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    // Add a new contact to the end of list
    @IBAction func insertNewContact(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if nameTextField.text != nil && nameTextField.text != "" {

            contactsArray.append(Contact(fullName: nameTextField.text!, phoneNumber: phoneTextField.text!))
            contactsTableView.reloadData()


        }

    }

    // Return no of sections from your list
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    // Return no of rows in each section from your list
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].count
    }

    // Insert a custom cell in your table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let contact = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.configContact(contact)
        return cell
    }


    // Delete a section when you swipe from right to left
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{
            sections.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            contactsTableView.reloadData() // xCode is confused sometimes and because my outlet var was named "tableView" and not "contactsTableView" it was trying to reload data from the parameter "tableView" of function and delete wasn't working at all. Now is deleting the whole section but I still need to work on it.
        }
    }


}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mutYR.jpg)

Comment: You are added a new contact into array (contactsArray) and using another array into table data source(sections)

Comment: please check your code as @MoayadAlkouz said.

Comment: You need to modify sections array after adding new object to contactsArray

Comment: And how will look my sections array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is contained in `contactsArray`, but your table's data source is `sections` array.  You need to update the `sections` array when `contactsArray` is changed.

Move your code that creates the `sections` array into its own method.  Call it after inserting data into `contactsArray` and before calling `reloadData()` on the table:

```
func createSectionsArray() {
    let firstLetters = contactsArray.map { $0.titleFirstLetter }
    let uniqueFirstLetters = Array(Set(firstLetters))

    sortedFirstLetters = uniqueFirstLetters.sorted()
    sections = sortedFirstLetters.map { firstLetter in
        return contactsArray
            .filter { $0.titleFirstLetter == firstLetter }
            .sorted { $0.fullName < $1.fullName }
    }
}
```

You'll also want to call it from `viewDidLoad()` in place of the code you removed to create the function.

---

**Deleting:**

For deleting, first make your `Contact` class conform to `Equatable`:

```
class Contact: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Contact, rhs: Contact) -> Bool {
        return lhs.fullName == rhs.fullName && lhs.phoneNumber == rhs.phoneNumber
    }

    var fullName: String
    var phoneNumber: String?

    init(fullName: String, phoneNumber: String) {
        self.fullName = fullName
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
    }
}
```

Then, when an item is deleted, use `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row` to look up the `contact`, find the `contact` in the `contactsArray` and remove it, regenerate the `sections` array, then reload the table:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let contact = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        if let index = contactsArray.index(of: contact) {
            contactsArray.remove(at: index)
            createSectionsArray()
            contactsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are awesome ! Is working perfectly ! If I was manager at Apple now you was hired by me. I love u !
Now if anyone can tell me why my delete is not working for each row and is deleting random rows I will really appreciate !
Thank you guys so much !!!

Comment: Are you trying to delete just one entry or the entire section?

Comment: Just one entry I want to delete.

Comment: Omg man you are amazing ! Is finally working ! Thank you so so so much for your time and for your help ! Thank you indeed again !